# remove_neighbors in STL like fashion

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I'm trying to implement, in STL fashion, an algorithm with the following functionallity:

**Given a range `[first,last)`, a neighborhood span `nSpan` and a (binary) predicate `Pred`, it removes elements from that range, so that `Pred` is NOT true for any remaining elements distant from each other at most `nSpan`**

**Examples** :

- `nSpan`=1 and `Pred`=Equality      => decays to the `std::unique` algorithm
- `nSpan`=2 and `Pred`=PointEquality => sanitize polyline

  ```
               + P2
               | 
               v
               ^
  P0           |          P4               P0          P1          P4
  +---->-------+---->------+    becomes    +---->-------+---->------+
             P1  P3
  ```
- `nSpan`=2 and `Pred`=Equality: ['a', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'd', 'f'] -> ['a', 'd', 'f']

In the last example, it's obvious that (to prevent the algorithm from going ambiguous) we **sweep from the first iterator and on, while checking up to nSpan distance** to remove elements (otherwise there would be multiple ways to remove elements).

My attempt so far (code listing below) has the following shortcomings:

- After a first sweep the new range may have new elements that are invalid, so a recursive functionality (again scaning from the *new start* towards the end) is needed to rescan the range (or maybe immitate recursion every time a removal happens)
- It's not implemented as a `remove` function but as an `erase` one (**I need a remove one** and it seems significantly more difficult) and that forces to supply the whole container as an argument instead of a range (ideally the algorithm should be container agnostic)

I'm listing a [first attempt](http://ideone.com/6d8l1A)

```
    template<typename Cont, typename It, class Pr>
    void erase_neighbors(Cont &cont, It first, It last, int nSpan, Pr Pred)
    {
        if (0 < nSpan && nSpan < std::distance(first, last)) for (It it2; (it2 = first), first != last; )
        {
            if (nSpan < std::distance(it2, last))
            {
                std::advance(it2, nSpan);
                if (Pred(*first, *it2))
                {
                    first = cont.erase(first, it2);
                    last = cont.end();
                    continue;
                }
            }
            ++first;
        }
    }
```

**Ideal signature**

```
template<typename It, class Pr>
It remove_neighbors(It first, It last, int nSpan, Pr Pred);
```

**Ideal implementation** : non c++11 and without boost (even though if there is a related boost algorithm I would appreciate knowing about it)

Comment: I hope you mean a range `[first, last)` ?

Comment: In your example of `['a', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'd', 'f'] -> ['a', 'd', 'f']`, where did 'b' and 'e' go? I don't see any reason why they would be removed. Or the polyline: P3 is removed because it's equal to P1 - but why was P2 removed?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik It all depends on the span of the neighborhood. In the array of chars case span=2 so the first 'a' is compared equal to the third element (to which it has a distance of 2) and all elements up to that are removed (the whole neighborhood except from the first item is removed). Then we proceed with 'd' which again has a match inside the valid span .... and so on

Comment: @sharth The output would ['a', 'b', 'c'] ofcourse (provided the predicate is the equality): there's no element in span=2 from a that equals a, there's no element in span=2 from b(the range ends) and the same goes for c. You can test with the code I [already provided](http://ideone.com/6d8l1A)

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou: Yeah. I had a misunderstanding of the problem that made it more complicated.

Comment: I don't follow. The answer of `['a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'f']` happily satisfies the requirement that "Equality is NOT true for any remaining elements distant from each other at most 2". There are in fact no equal elements remaining, at any distance.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Please note in the question the part _it's obvious that (to prevent the algorithm from going ambiguous) we sweep from the first iterator and on, while checking up to nSpan distance to remove elements (otherwise there would be multiple ways to remove elements)_

Comment: What should be the answer in this case: `[a b c b a]`, span 2? Here, removing `[c b]` would bring the last `a` within range of the first. Should the algorithm backtrack? Your procedural description doesn't seem to allow for this possibility.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Please note in the question the part _so a recursive functionality (again scaning from the new start towards the end) is needed to rescan the range_, mentioned as a shortcoming of my solution so far (one of the two reasons I'm posting this as a quesiton in SO)

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou: This is a very strange algorithm to me (which isn't in itself a problem).  To verify the accuracy of the answers, can you post a short list of sample inputs / outputs, hopefully including a few edge cases?

Comment: @MooingDuck As soon as I have some time, I'll verify/test both answers (to pick one) and provide some samples or a real world usage cases

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou: Specifically, I was thinking of writing an answer as well, but I'm not positive I understand the question 100%.  Several sample inputs->outputs would verify that I do (or don't) have the correct understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the extent I understand the problem statement, this seems to do what you want. See it [in action](http://ideone.com/ryTLcs):

```
template<typename It, class Pr>
It remove_neighbors(It first, It last, int nSpan, Pr Pred) {
  if (first == last || nSpan <= 0) return last;

  It lastGood = first;
  It cur = first;
  ++cur;
  for (; cur != last; ++cur) {
    bool found = false;
    It back = lastGood;
    for (int i = nSpan; i > 0; --i, --back) {
      if (Pred(*back, *cur)) {
        found = true;
        lastGood = back;
        break;
      }
      if (back == first) break;
    }

    if (!found) {
      ++lastGood;
      *lastGood = std::move(*cur);
    }
  }
  ++lastGood;
  return lastGood;
}
```

This makes no more than `N` moves/copies, and no more than `N * nSpan` invocations of `Pred`.

Comment: Perfect. The implementation is very close to the STL style `remove` algorithms + the backtracking is handled ellegantly. It works (on everything I tested so far) as expected and works fast. (I hope you don't mind if I use it with `std::swap(*lastGood, *cur)` insted of `*lastGood = std::move(*cur)` to maintained the removed elements just in case)

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid both the problems you listed, by maintaining a table of next element. So each position will point to the next valid position that qualifies as the `good` neighbour without violating the predicate, like so:

```
map<unsigned, unsigned> neigh_table;
while(it != end){
    neigh = startneigh = it + 1;
    do{
        if(pred(it, neigh)) //if predicate fails, restart with a new neighbour
            neigh = startneigh = neigh + 1;
        else
            ++neigh;
    }while(neigh - startneigh < range && neigh != end);

    neigh_table[it-start] = startneigh - start;
    it = neigh;
}
```

At the end of the operation, you can either:

1. Return the lookup table of neighbours for the user to process or
2. Return a list of the iterators, separate from the container, like a vector/list of iterators that are neighbours, by walking the map yourself inside the function.

In either case you won't be able to modify the container, without passing in the actual container to the function. This is why functions such as `stl::remove` don't modify the length of the container. See [remove-erase idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom), for examples of how to actually modify the container, using stl::remove.

Comment: Nice and out of the box thinking!